Environment "Breakout" not found in OpenAI Gym
I'm trying to create the "Breakout" environment using OpenAI Gym in Python, but I'm encountering an error stating that the environment doesn't exist. Here's my code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import time

import gym

env_name = "Breakout-v0"

env = gym.make(env_name)

However, when I run this code, I get the following error:NameNotFound: Environment Breakout doesn't exist.
I've already installed Gym and its dependencies, including the Atari environments, using pip install gym[atari]. I've also checked for typos in the environment name and restarted my kernel, but I still get the same error.
Could someone please help me understand why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it?
